# Having defficulties in adding UISwipeGesture recognizer to progress circle bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiswipegesturerecognizer

When i try to add tap gesture, it works only to the side of the view where progress circle is not drawn. I have tried many ways but doesnt work it out for me any clue will be higly appreciated.
where cirularProgress is the view when i try to add swipe gesture into that but didnt worked. Here is the code.

```
// Creating Circular Progress Bar
- (void) createCircularProgress{
    self.percentageDoughnut = [[MCPercentageDoughnutView alloc] initWithFrame:self.circularProgress.frame];
    self.percentageDoughnut.dataSource              = self;
    self.percentageDoughnut.percentage              = steps/10000.0;
    self.percentageDoughnut.linePercentage          = 0.15;
    self.percentageDoughnut.animationDuration       = 2;
    self.percentageDoughnut.decimalPlaces           = 1;
    self.percentageDoughnut.textStyle = MCPercentageDoughnutViewTextStyleUserDefined;
    self.percentageDoughnut.textLabel.text          = @"0 Steps";
    self.percentageDoughnut.showTextLabel           = YES;
    self.percentageDoughnut.animatesBegining        = YES;
    self.percentageDoughnut.fillColor               = [UIColor greenColor];
    self.percentageDoughnut.unfillColor             = [MCUtil iOS7DefaultGrayColorForBackground];
    self.percentageDoughnut.textLabel.textColor     = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.percentageDoughnut.textLabel.font          = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:50];
    self.percentageDoughnut.gradientColor1          = [UIColor greenColor];
    self.percentageDoughnut.gradientColor2          = [MCUtil iOS7DefaultGrayColorForBackground];  
    [self.view addSubview:self.percentageDoughnut];
}
```

The basic function of library

```
- (UIView*)viewForCenterOfPercentageDoughnutView:(MCPercentageDoughnutView *)pecentageDoughnutView
                              withCenterView:(UIView *)centerView {
//    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
//    UIViewController *progressContentViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"progressContent"];
//    progressContentViewController.view.frame = centerView.bounds;
//
//    return progressContentViewController.view;
// Uncomment to see an image example
//*
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];
imageView.frame = centerView.bounds;

return imageView;
self.percentageDoughnut.showTextLabel = YES;
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:centerView.bounds];
/*label.layer.borderWidth = 1;
 label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
 NSMutableAttributedString *s = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"GB(59%)"];
 [s addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:40] range:NSMakeRange(0, 2)];
 [s addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20] range:NSMakeRange(2, 3)];*/
// label.text = _getSteps.text;
return label;}
```

I tried swipe gesture by adding this code to viewdidLoad:

```
[circularProgress setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];    
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)]; 
    // Setting the swipe direction.
    [swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
    // Adding the swipe gesture on image view
 [circularProgress addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
    [circularProgress addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
```

And checking out by printing in NSLog

```
- (void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipe {   
    if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
        NSLog(@"Left Swipe");
    } 
    if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight) {
        NSLog(@"Right Swipe");
    }    
}
```

Circular Progress UIView is defined in header file

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *circularProgress;
```

Comment: You haven't mentioned `circularProgress` view earlier in code.. could you post a bit more info about that view?

Comment: Now its edited, thanks for asking and kindly help me in this regards

Comment: Emm, you add your `percentageDoughunt` to main view of viewController: `[self.view addSubview:self.percentageDoughnut]`, whereas you add swipe gesture to some binded (circularProgress) view from xib. It will make it easier if you do a screenshot of the view, and show where is each element.

Comment: it is just simple UIView which is added to xib.

Comment: i tried to add [self.view addSubview:self.percentageDoughnut] and i also added UIGestureRecognizerDelegate to class

Comment: Any help to add UISwipeGesture